# Conversão de datas no banco de dados

Tags: data, conversão-de-tipo

Como converter uma data que está no formato `DDMMYYYY` para `YYYYMMDD`?

Estou tendo problemas para enviar estes dados para diferentes bases SQL, tendo em vista que cada uma foi elaborada de um jeito e já estão alimentadas.

Comment: Poderia especificar o banco de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu banco de dados for MySQL você pode usar uma função do mysql ao fazer o insert.

`DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y-%m-%d').`

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp